# Windows Phone 8 extras-info addition info

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, cellular-network

So I have a windows phone bought from service provider A, that I want to use to develop an app for service provider B. now the problem (I believe) is that service provider A has preloaded info on the windows phone under the extras+info -> additional info (like hardcoded a value). So what happens is although I put a SIM from service provider B into the phone it still gets detected that the device belongs to service provider A.

Now my question is, can I somehow overwrite that info on the phone using my app, or is it even possible to change that info, could it maybe be another setting or something on the phone that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe this is not possible without OEM capabilities.

Comment: ... which makes this off-topic for SO as it isn't a public SDK.